# In Python 3.7, when using this random.choice code, why are the [ ] brackets and the asterisk needed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sides=random.choice([*range(3,10),360])
```

The purpose of this code is to pick a random number from 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 360.

Comment: As for the brackets, [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) takes a single argument.

Comment: The brackets is to create a list and the asterisk is to unpack the range into the list. Basically, it's the same as `list_to_chose_from = [*range(3, 10), 360]` and then `sides = random.choice(list_to_chose_from)`.

Comment: `range(3,10)` delivers 3-9 ... not 10.